# Why does the SHA256 of Raspbian file image never correspond to the one indicated on the website?

Tags: raspbian-stretch

Every time I [download Raspbian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) (last time Raspbian Stretch with desktop) I try to verify SHA256. However, every time the result is different from the one on the website, although I am quite sure the download was successful and without manipulation.

Why is that? Am I calculating in a wrong way?

The last time I generated the sha256 on OSX with the command `shasum -a 256 2018-06-27-raspbian-stretch.img`

Comment: side note - "I am quite sure the download was successful and without manipulation." - no you aren't.

Comment: If you're getting the hash from the same channel as the file it claims to verify, it's actually only a checksum (detecting accidental corruption).  An attacker that could replace the image could also modify the hash to match.

Comment: @immibis No you are right I am not in one particular occasion, but if everytime the sha256 does not correspond is more likely something is not right in how I am calculating it rather than me being attacked on every download I do in different situations with different networks and different everything....At least I think so otherwise I would have to think I am under attack every time but I am not that paranoid

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The SHA-256 checksum on the downloads page is for the ZIP file, not the IMG file.

Comment: It confused me because it seems OSX extract directly the zip file so I did not get it was downloaded as zip.

Comment: You'll find the .zip file is there in the parent folder of the location the contents were extracted to.  This took me a while to get used to, too. :)

Comment: Sidenote: Provided checksums are in general **directly for the downloaded file**, not for any files **inside** a downloaded archive/container.